# SBT: Enable/Disable fatal warnings only for certain command alias?

Tags: scala, sbt

Absolute sbt newbie here, so I might be missing something basic:

I want to have a particular command alias like `build-special` which runs the regular `build` command, but with the `"-Xfatal-warnings"` fatal warning flag enabled (or disabled, depending on what we make the default.)

How would this be done?

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/build.sbt has a `fatalWarnings` setting that accomplishes this, except for the command-alias part. (Sorry I'm too lazy to write a real answer, but perhaps seeing this example will be helpful, regardless.)